# /** Fatal error: Call to a member function getSource() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\app\code\local\Gclone\Deal\Model\Deal.php on line 82

Tags: php, function, call, member

i am new at php & i have downloaded Contus groupclone nulled code. i made its connection to mysql database but when i want to run it i got this error. my local sever is wamp 2.2 and uses apache 2.2.21 , php 5.3.8 and mysql 5.5.16 on windows vista.
i 'd be appreciate if someone could help me.

```
  public function urlCollections()
  {
      if ($this->isLicense() === true) {
          $attribute = Mage::getmodel("eav/config")->getAttribute("catalog_product", "562");
          $cityValue = array();
        * foreach ($attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true) as $option) {*
              $cityValue[$option['label']] = $option['value'];
              $storeId                     = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
              $city                        = $option['value'];

              if ($city != "") {
                  $cityName     = $option['label'];
                  $cityName     = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9^-]", "", $cityName);
                  $cityName     = str_replace(" ", "-", $cityName);
                  $cityName     = strtolower($cityName);
                  $requestPath  = "deal/" . $cityName . ".html";
                  $realPath     = "deal/index/index/city/" . $city;
                  $resource     = Mage::getsingleton("core/resource");
                  $read         = $resource->getConnection("read");
                  $tPrefix      = ( boolean ) Mage::getconfig()->getTablePrefix();
                  $rewriteTable = "magentocore_url_rewrite";
                  $idPath       = "deal/index/index/city/" . $city;
                  $urlRewrite   = $read->select()->from(array(
                      "ur" => $rewriteTable
                  ), array(
                      "ur.request_path"
                  ))->where("ur.id_path =? ", $idPath)->where("ur.store_id =? ", $storeId)->where("ur.is_system =?", 0);
                  $cityUrl      = $read->fetchRow($urlRewrite);
                  if (empty($cityUrl)) {
                      $urlCheck     = $read->select()->from(array(
                          "ur" => $rewriteTable
                      ), array(
                          "ur.request_path"
                      ))->where("ur.request_path =? ", $requestPath)->where("ur.store_id =? ", $storeId)->where("ur.is_system =?", 0);
                      $cityUrlCheck = $read->fetchRow($urlCheck);
                      if (!empty($cityUrlCheck)) {
                          $requestPath = "deal/" . $cityName . "-" . $city . ".html";
                      }
                      $executeQuery = $read->query("INSERT INTO {$rewriteTable} (`store_id`, `category_id`, `product_id`, `id_path`, `request_path`, `target_path`, `is_system`, `options`, `description`) VALUES ({$storeId}, NULL, NULL, '{$realPath}', '{$requestPath}', '{$realPath}', '0', '', NULL)");
                  }
              }
          }
          return $cityValue;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The error means that you're treating the `$attribute` variable as an object by calling the `->` operator, but PHP is not recognizing it as an object type.

```
$attribute = Mage::getmodel("eav/config")->getAttribute("catalog_product", "562");
$cityValue = array();
* foreach ($attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true) as $option) {*
$cityValue[$option['label']] = $option['value'];'
```

You have a `*` before and after your `foreach`, Why? Perform a `var_dump()` or `print_r()` on `$attribute` right after the assignment. You could even do a `gettype()` call.

Comment: hi again. * isn't really in my code i just want to mark it here to show which line has  problem and i dont have any idea how it is gone there ! i dont exactly understand how to fix it. would u write corrected line for me here? thank u

Comment: Tell us the output of `var_dump($attribute);` right after it's assignment.

Comment: i added code like this:     $attribute= Mage::getmodel("eav/config")->getAttribute("catalog_product", "562");
   var_dump($attribute);
              $cityValue = array();
             foreach ($attribute ->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true) as $option) {

Comment: Comment out your entire foreach block and run your script. tell us the output. `var_dump()` will give you detailed info about the `$attribute` variable. `Mage::getmodel("eav/config")->getAttribute("catalog_product", "562");` is not actually returning an object.

Comment: and i got same error and another boolean False error when i ran it on my local server

Comment: Inspect your model functions `getmodel()` and `getAttributes()`. Post them here too. Also, how could you have the same error if you've commented out the line that was causing it? Are you sure it's not slightly different?

Comment: i commented out tow foreach block but another line: $defaultCity = $attribute->getDefaultValue(); cause  Call to a member function getDefaultValue() on a non-object and when i commented it too, magento page appears whit Invalid attribute name: City error and this is obvious because i have commented it !

Comment: it seems there are more unsolvable problem with my nulled source code. dont u know any other group buying and discount source code that i could run it without problem. this is very important for me because group buying is still new and intact field of business in our country and i cant buy a source because of sanction against my country.